# Change sprite background position that is inside a content tag

Tags: css

I have this tag:

```
a[title="BAG"]:after {
 ... 
 content: url("../images/mainsprite.png");
 ...
}
```

And since the image is a sprite that includes other icons I need to change it's position.
Any ideas?

Comment: I usually see `background-image` being used, I assume you are using it for another reason but just in case can you provide your full css class for `a[title="BAG"]:after`

Comment: The goal is to change the content and not set the property, unfortunately the background-image doesn't work in this case scenario.

Comment: you will need to add width and height if you are using background image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `content` use `background image`

```
a[title="BAG"]:after {
  content:'';
  width:xxpx;
  height:xxpx;
  background:url();
  background-position:xxpx xxpx;
}
```

Comment: Yes! That did it, setting the content as none allows me to set the background-position with no troubles, thanks.